# Sonarqube not starting up because of elastic search error

Tags: java, node.js, elasticsearch, sonarqube

How I can fix these error so that sonarqube web server start?

**System info**:
4gb ram
20gb ssd
Ubuntu 20
GCP instance
openjdk 11.0.16 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)
Database postgreysql

added this config

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
vm.max_map_count=524288
fs.file-max=131072

sudo nano /etc/security/limits.conf
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitNPROC=8192
```

Here is the error log from es.log

```
    nux/5.10.0-17-cloud-amd64/amd64], JVM[Debian/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/11.0.16/11.0.16+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1]
    2022.08.28 07:25:58 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM home [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64]
    2022.08.28 07:25:58 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-9.6.0.59041/temp, -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djna.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-9.6.0.59041/temp, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Dcom.redhat.fips=false, -Des.enforce.bootstrap.checks=true, -Xmx512m, -Xms512m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Des.path.home=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-9.6.0.59041/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-9.6.0.59041/temp/conf/es, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar, -Des.bundled_jdk=false]
    2022.08.28 07:25:59 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [analysis-common]
    2022.08.28 07:25:59 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [lang-painless]
    2022.08.28 07:25:59 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
    2022.08.28 07:25:59 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [reindex]
    2022.08.28 07:25:59 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
    2022.08.28 07:25:59 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded
    2022.08.28 07:25:59 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [15gb], net total_space [19.4gb], types [ext4]
    2022.08.28 07:25:59 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [512mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
    2022.08.28 07:26:00 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [hMHntBcSQP2N_BO7RmEq_Q], cluster name [sonarqube], roles [data_frozen, master, remote_cluster_client, data, data_content, data_hot, data_warm, data_cold, ingest]
    2022.08.28 07:26:10 INFO  es[][o.e.t.NettyAllocator] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=unpooled, suggested_max_allocation_size=256kb, factors={es.unsafe.use_unpooled_allocator=null, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=1mb, heap_size=512mb}]
    2022.08.28 07:26:10 INFO  es[][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings] using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]
    2022.08.28 07:26:10 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]
    2022.08.28 07:26:11 INFO  es[][o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState] gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually
    2022.08.28 07:26:12 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized
    2022.08.28 07:26:12 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ...
    2022.08.28 07:26:12 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address {127.0.0.1:33021}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:33021}
    2022.08.28 07:26:13 INFO  es[][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks] explicitly enforcing bootstrap checks
    2022.08.28 07:26:13 INFO  es[][o.e.c.c.Coordinator] cluster UUID [Zr7bq2njQaGGtYQLTPjNwA]
    2022.08.28 07:26:13 INFO  es[][o.e.c.s.MasterService] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[{sonarqube}{hMHntBcSQP2N_BO7RmEq_Q}{cPlSdljHSWaa_qh9tCJnAw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:33021}{cdfhimrsw} elect leader, _BECOME_MASTER_TASK_, _FINISH_ELECTION_], term: 5, version: 9, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{sonarqube}{hMHntBcSQP2N_BO7RmEq_Q}{cPlSdljHSWaa_qh9tCJnAw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:33021}{cdfhimrsw}]}
    2022.08.28 07:26:13 INFO  es[][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] master node changed {previous [], current [{sonarqube}{hMHntBcSQP2N_BO7RmEq_Q}{cPlSdljHSWaa_qh9tCJnAw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:33021}{cdfhimrsw}]}, term: 5, version: 9, reason: Publication{term=5, version=9}
    2022.08.28 07:26:13 INFO  es[][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
    2022.08.28 07:26:13 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] started
    2022.08.28 07:26:13 INFO  es[][o.e.g.GatewayService] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
    2022.08.28 07:26:20 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopping ...
    2022.08.28 07:26:20 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopped
    2022.08.28 07:26:20 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closing ...
    2022.08.28 07:26:20 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closed
```

Comment: From those logs, I don't seen anything that could explain why elasticsearch is stopping. How do you start that container? Looks like container is being restarted.

Comment: Sonarqube service created at this location
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service

Comment: Here is the content of sonarqube service file https://gist.githubusercontent.com/prosenjit-manna/cac325b49649c3252b21c804fb57b7cf/raw/31b5d8a55800f9629847d913eb89ad6e5e2e7d24/sonarqube.service

Comment: allright, do you get anything from `journalctl -u sonarqube`

Comment: Hey, I run your commands and you can check the log from here https://gist.github.com/prosenjit-manna/f74aa7d98b111a6cb33fb6a3e93f4d95

Comment: Sounds like something wrong with your systemd unit. Docs does something different, see: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/operate-server/

Comment: Hey thanks for your info, I checked your docs. And I understand my sonar. service file is different. 

Then I just copy and paste sonar. service from the documentation. But still not solved the issue. 

Thanks  for your help.

Comment: well... for sure something's wrong with that systemd unit. sonarqube isn't crashing, it's being restarted on a loop. check back on journalctl logs.